# how to get the internet Address of client machine in the Web service C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I want Client machine internet IP Address in asp.net web service for that I am using following code

```
string IPaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPaddress))
    IPaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPaddress))
    IPaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but Here I am getting the client machine local IP But * I am looking public IP/ Internet IP of the client machine*

Please Help me, anybody.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of attributes of Request which provides client IP address.
Here is the code:

```
private string GetClientIpAddress (HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
        if ( request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext") )
            {
            return ((HttpContextWrapper) request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
            }
        if ( request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name) )
            {
            var prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty) request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
            return prop.Address;
            }

        if ( request.Headers.Contains("X-Forwarded-For") )
            {
            return request.Headers.GetValues("X-Forwarded-For").FirstOrDefault();
            }

        // Self-hosting using Owin. Add below code if you are using Owin communication listener
        if ( request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_OwinContext") )
            {
            var owinContext = (OwinContext) request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];
            if ( owinContext?.Request != null )
                {
                return owinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
                }
            }

        if ( HttpContext.Current != null )
            {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }

        return null;

        }
```

Hope it will work.
~Prasad

Comment: @Did it work? if not please let us know correct way to get the client IP address. ~ Prasad

Answer (score 0):

You get the IP address of the connection by which the client is connecting to your server. If this is within the same network, you won't see a public IP address, because the connection is not routed over the internet.